# select all options chosen plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am trying to deselect all values of options which allow multiple selection by using this code for [chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)

```
var lstViewCities= $('#lstViewCities');
$(lstViewCities).find("option").each(function(item) {
       $(item).attr('selected', '');
});
$(lstViewCities).trigger("liszt:updated");
```

but nothing is happening and same for selecting all option

```
var lstViewCities= $('#lstViewCities');
$(lstViewCities).find("option").each(function(item) {
       $(item).attr('selected', 'selected');
});
$(lstViewCities).trigger("liszt:updated");
```

[**edit**]
here is [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/3qrEQ/8/) for above problem 

[**/edit**]

Doesn't it support selecting multiple options using code or what?
Your answers will be surely of great help, looking forward to your responses. Thanks :)

Comment: Zaksh can you add that jsfiddle from yesterday evening? I'll help answer the question.

Comment: @Sam here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/3qrEQ/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $('.search-choice-close', '.search-choice').trigger('click');
}
```

In single select you might use:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $('#testChosen_chzn').find('.search-choice-close').trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: dude I really appreciate your effort, i worked like a charm but what if I have multiple select boxed and I just want to rest one, definitely I can't make that with wild card entry based on class name

Comment: Added code working for single chosen you use:

#SELECTID_chzn as selector

Answer (score 3):

As stated here: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/1559

You can do this with:

```
// Deselect
$('#my_select_box option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
$('#my_select_box').trigger('chosen:updated');

// Select
$('#my_select_box option').attr('selected', 'selected');
$('#my_select_box').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

I just used it and it's working, the problem is if the events get updated in a next release
things will just stop working

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$(lstViewCities).find("option").each(function(this) {
   $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

replace 'this' instead of 'item'